# Why does my program keep printing "0" instead of what the functions tell it?

Tags: python, function, numbers

My code keeps generating "0" and I'm not sure what to do. My instructions are to write a function that finds Emilia Numbers, and then use it to count how many Emilia numbers would you find for the numbers from 1 to 1000

```
def is_emilia_number(num):
        # Find all the factors of the number
        factors = []
        for i in range(1, num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)

    # Check if the number has at least two sets of factors where the sum of one set equals the difference of another set
    for i in range(len(factors)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(factors)):
            for k in range(j+1, len(factors)):
                for l in range(k+1, len(factors)):
                    if factors[i] + factors[j] == factors[k] - factors[l]:
                        return True

    return False

# Initialize a counter to 0
counter = 0

# Iterate through the numbers from 1 to 1000
for num in range(1, 1001):
    # Check if the number is an Emilia number
    if is_emilia_number(num):
        counter += 1

# Print the counter
print(counter) # should print 8
```

I tried working on the functions separately too but I don't know why it's not working. here's examples:
a positive Integer will be an “Emilia Number” if it has at least two sets of factors where the sum of one set equals the difference of another set.
6 is an Emilia Number.  It has a sets of factors (6,1) and (2,3) where 2 + 3 = 6 – 1
30 is an Emilia Number.  It has sets of factors (10,3) and (15,2) where 10 + 3 = 15 – 2
84 is an Emilia Number.  It has sets of factors (21,4) and (28,3) where 21 + 4 = 28 – 3

Comment: Is the indentation in the function correct? Also from what you described, meaning the function is never returning True. So it only makes sense that your function is not running till the part you added return True. By default, all functions returns a None instead.

Comment: what do you mean it's never True?

Comment: I just mean, by observation you are always getting counter=0. Means, for every integer that ran through your function(), it never reaches the part where it returns True..

Comment: Due to the lower limits of the ranges there is always `i < j < k < l`. E. g. for 6 `factors == [1, 2, 3, 6]` so that `k` and `l` can only refer to factors 3 and 6 with difference -3.

Comment: Your expression `factors[k] - factors[l]` will always be negative whereas `factors[i] + factors[j]` is always positive. Therefore you certainly can't find any equal pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies within your nested for loop. You're continuously adding the start of the loop by 1 meaning it'll skip over some of the values that you're trying to use for comparison. You can try swapping out your nested for loop with this one:

```
for i in factors:
    for j in factors:
        if i != j:
            for k in factors:
                if i != k:
                    for l in factors:
                        if k != l and i != l:
                            if i + j == k - l:
                                print(i + j)
                                print(i, j, k, l)
                                return True
```

There seems to be a lot more than 8 numbers that satisfy the requirement though. I added in two prints to show which values satisfy the requirement.

This is the full code that I edited:

```
def is_emilia_number(num):
    # Find all the factors of the number
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)

    for i in factors:
        for j in factors:
            if i != j:
                for k in factors:
                    if i != k:
                        for l in factors:
                            if k != l and i != l:
                                if i + j == k - l:
                                    print(i + j)
                                    print(i, j, k, l)
                                    return True

# Initialize a counter to 0
counter = 0

# Iterate through the numbers from 1 to 1000
for num in range(1,1000):
    # Check if the number is an Emilia number
    if is_emilia_number(num):
        counter += 1

# Print the counter
print(counter) # should print 8
```

Comment: For me this code keeps printing numbers that don't stop. Like I can't see what's being generated

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of the definition of Emilia numbers is incorrect. I think you are meant to consider pairs of factors `(f,g)` where `f*g==n`.A number is an Emilia number iff it has two pairs of factors `(f,g)` and `(h,k)` such that f+g=k-h. If you just allow arbitrary pairs factors of `n` (without requiring that they multiply to `n`) then there are many more than 8 solutions.

If you don't restrict your attention to pairs of factors `(f,g)` where `f*g==n` then consider any multiple of 12. It will have `1,2,3,4` among its factors. Note that 4-1 == 1+2 so this number would get classified as an Emilia number. This would mean that any multiple of 12 is an Emilia number. There are 83 multiples of 12 less than 1000. If there are only 8 Emilia numbers less than 1000 then all multiples of 12 can't be Emilia numbers. Therefore I am pretty sure that you should restrict your attention to pairs of factors `(f,g)` where `f*g==n`

The following function only considers pairs of factors that multiply to the input number. However with this implementation there are still 34 Emilia numbers between 1 and 1000. This function will print the reason for classifying a number as Emilia. As far I can tell its results are all ok, and there are 34 Emilia numbers between 1 and 1000.

```
def is_emilia_number(num):
    # Find all the factors of the number
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    for f in factors:
        g = num // f
        sum = f + g
        for h in factors: 
            i = num // h
            if i > h:
                (i, h) = (h, i)
            diff = h-i
            if sum == diff:
                print(f"num: {num} is an Emilia number because {f}+{g} == {h}-{i} {f}*{g}={f*g} {h}*{i}={h*i}")
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Nothing is printing..

Comment: In your original code above replace the implementation of “is_emilia_number” with the function that I just provided. Run your original program with the new function. It will print.

Answer (score 0):

The original approach to solving the problem does too much work in that it computes all of the possible factor differences for each factor sum. Here is a solution that computes all of the possible `factor sums` and `factor differences` in one pass over the factors, and then checks to see if the set of sums and the set of differences has any intersection:

```
def is_emilia_number(num):
    # Find all the factors of the number
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    sums = set()
    diffs = set()
    for f in factors:
        g = num // f
        sums.add(f+g)
        diffs.add(f-g)
        sum = f + g
        diff = f-g
    return not sums.isdisjoint(diffs)

counter = 0

# Iterate through the numbers from 1 to 1000
for num in range(1, 1001):
    # Check if the number is an Emilia number
    if is_emilia_number(num):
        counter += 1

# Print the counter
print(counter) # should print 8
```